# Should you upgrade ExpressionEngine or Multiple Site Manager (MSM) first?

Tags: multi-site-manager, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I am upgrading MSM and ExpressionEngine.

Which upgrade do I need to complete first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always make sure you are running the most recent version of ExpressionEngine when installing or upgrading Multiple Site Manager.

**Also consider:** when you buy additional licenses you're technically completing an upgrade of MSM, and so each time you add new licenses, you need to make sure you're on the most recent version of ExpressionEngine.